# How to destructure a obj and still be able to get the NOT destruchtured obj?

Tags: javascript, object, destructuring

I have this function:

```
testFn({email: "test@gmail.com", password: "123"})
```

You can now destructure it:

```
function testFn({email, password}) {
 console.log(email, password)
}
```

> test@gmail.com 123

But is there a way to get the initial object?

I have heared of this syntax but it doesn´t work:

```
function testFn({email, password, ...objectView}) {
 console.log(email, password,objectView)
}
```

> test@gmail.com 123 {email: "test@gmail.com", password: "123"}

Comment: The spread syntax in your last example does work, it just doesn't do what you are asking about; it returns an object containing the properties that remain after the explicitly destructured properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object.

```js
testFn({email: "test@gmail.com", password: "123"})

function testFn({email, password}) {
 console.log(email, password);
 console.log(arguments[0])
}
```

Comment: how to do this in a arrowfunction?

Comment: @oxygen You would have to destructure the object inside the method body.

Answer (score 0):

You can restructure the argument object in the function instead of within the parameter list:

```js
function testFn( arg) {
   const {email, password} = arg;
   console.log( email, password, arg);
}

testFn( {email:"foo@example.com", password: 123});
```